# How to get file handle from view's base address

Tags: c, winapi, memory-mapped-files, kernel32

Suppose you either have some file's handle and you want to get all views (memory base addresses) in your process or you don't have the handle but you have the view and you want the handle. Any ideas how to do it? It should be possible since the function FlushViewOfFile also only needs the base address to your view to write the file. I tried searching through exports in kernel32.dll, googled a little bit, no success though.

Comment: Mapping the file into memory gives it to the memory subsystem to manage, which is why the file handle isn't needed to flush; so, there's no mapping from the view back to the handle. You need to keep the handle around if you need it later.

Comment: I don't quite follow. You say its done by memory manager, that means memory manager is where its supposed to keep track of things, that means there is a place with some sort of mapping.

Comment: @stupid_idiot HerrJoeBob is saying that it doesn't need to keep that information so it doesn't. Going behind its back and messing with the file handle itself is probably a bad idea anyway. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: My point is to make series of order dependent modifications to memory mapped file and then write the changes. Using WriteFile seemed to me as cleaner way in case of modifications other than just replacing data. I won't always have the file handle e.g. in cases of named mapped files - the file may not have been created in my program.

Comment: You definitely don't want to mix memory-mapping and using straight WriteFile(), as the coherency of the file isn't guaranteed in that case. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I dont mind reopening the file, CreateFile is not that slow. But you are right, better would be to create extended memory mappping and do the changes there, yet that takes a lot of copying memory and I dont much like that.